# need to simplify inserts into a loop for PDO MySQL

Tags: mysql, loops, pdo, insert

so I have this code (below) and I would like to simplify that stack of repeating lines into a single, simple loop that given and imput (say 9) incriments those values for the URL and LISTNUM. This may be really simple but I can't get my brain around it for some reason - simply because I am not sure how to deal with variables INSIDE other variable... like $_POST[$n]

```
if ($_POST[subby] == "subby" )
{

        try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=db2asdfasdf.net;dbname=adsfasdf04', $user, $pass);
          echo "Connected\n";
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) {
          die("Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage());
        }

        try {  
          $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

          $dbh->beginTransaction();
          $dbh->exec("insert into vim_playlist4 (url, listnum) values ($_POST[video1], 1)");
          $dbh->exec("insert into vim_playlist4 (url, listnum) values ($_POST[video2], 2)");
           $dbh->exec("insert into vim_playlist4 (url, listnum) values ($_POST[video3], 3)");
            $dbh->exec("insert into vim_playlist4 (url, listnum) values ($_POST[video4], 4)");
             $dbh->exec("insert into vim_playlist4 (url, listnum) values ($_POST[video5], 5)");
              $dbh->exec("insert into vim_playlist4 (url, listnum) values ($_POST[video6], 6)");
                      $dbh->exec("insert into vim_playlist4 (url, listnum) values ($_POST[video7], 7)");
                              $dbh->exec("insert into vim_playlist4 (url, listnum) values ($_POST[video8], 8)");
                                      $dbh->exec("insert into vim_playlist4 (url, listnum) values ($_POST[video9], 9)");


          $dbh->commit();

        } 
        catch (Exception $e) {
          $dbh->rollBack();
          echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

}
else 
{}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do an insert like this:

```
insert into vim_playlist4 (url, listnum) values 
($_POST[video1], 1), 
($_POST[video2], 2),
($_POST[video3], 3), 
($_POST[video4], 4)
```

Don't forget to sanitize your data before you insert it, because you currently have lots of SQL injection prone areas.

Here is how you can sanitize the data:

```
<?php
$dbh->beginTransaction();
$sql = $dbh->prepare("insert into vim_playlist4 (url, listnum) values 
(?, 1), (?, 2), (?, 3), (?, 4), (?, 5), (?, 6), (?, 7), (?, 8), (?, 9)");

$sql->execute(array($_POST["video1"], $_POST["video2"], $_POST["video3"],
    $_POST["video4"], $_POST["video5"] ,$_POST["video6"], $_POST["video7"],
    $_POST["video8"], $_POST["video9"]));

$dbh->commit();
```

Comment: thanks so much! I don't quite understand the sanitize advice. I switched from MySQL queries to the PDO system because people were telling me that I was vulnerable to attack and that PDO was the solution. How then is this still insecure?

Comment: I updated the php part. It shows one of the ways to sanitize the data.